# Handle non-picture URL with SDWebImage

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I am using `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:andResize:withContentMode:success:` method of SDWebImage. When I provide it with correct URL, pointing to picture, it works well. But when I feed it some non-picture URL (e.g. http://www.yandex.ru), SDWebImage does nothing, even success and failure blocks are not called.

How should I detect if SDWebImage would not get image from the URL specified?

Comment: why not detect before you pass to method?

Comment: I write kind of a reader and should display an image from RSS feed. If one decides to put non-image url in his/her feed I can not foresee all the possibilities.

Comment: There is also option of placeholder image in SDWebImage...

Comment: @Leena Forgot to say, if there is no image, I hide the ImageView in success/failure block (which does not get called in my case). And it seems wrong to keep a placeholder for surely not an image link.

Comment: If you want to make sure the image link, you need to inform user in other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update SDWebImage to newest version and use new function instead of old: 
`sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock`

Comment: Thanks, will keep this in mind, but currently not an option for our rather big old-fashioned project.

Comment: @AndreySolovyov you can very easy download new version from github, or better, add it as submodule to your project or add it via cocoapods. Old version have issue with no firing completion handler because of incorrect url, in new versions it is fixed...

Comment: @AndreySolovyov also it is very easy to update your old project to new one - you just need to write custom category for UIImageView, which use old function name, but call new SDWebImage functions

Comment: Tried the latest version of SDWebImage and it worked! Now it generates the following error:

`Error Domain=SDWebImageErrorDomain Code=0 "Downloaded image has 0 pixels" UserInfo=0x146973a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Downloaded image has 0 pixels}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the SDWebImageManager instead:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:imageURL
                 options:0
                 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
                 {
                     // progression tracking code
                 }
                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
                 {
                     if (image)
                     {
                         // do something with image
                     }
                 }];
```

And then check the error value in the completed block.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I do not have this method in SDWebImageManager (maybe old version of SDWI). The closest I have found is `downloadWithURL:delegate:options:userInfo:success:failure:`, still no luck.

Comment: @AndreySolovyov what version are you using?

Comment: Can not say for sure, it dated 14/03/12

Comment: @AndreySolovyov Based on the code, it looks like the SDWebImageManager is still there, you'll just need to implement a SDWebImageManagerDelegate that handles `- (void)imageDownloader:(SDWebImageDownloader *)downloader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;` and use `- (void)downloadWithURL:(NSURL *)url delegate:(id<SDWebImageManagerDelegate>)delegate;` on the SDWebImageManager instead.